# Integrate Doxygen API documentation with Codeplex website

Tags: doxygen, codeplex

We use Doxygen to generate API documentation, this works well. But we cannot host the files on Codeplex, because when using the SVN url of the HTML files the file code is shown not the parsed HTML.
Here's a simple test: https://mapwingis.svn.codeplex.com/svn/MapWinGIS/trunk/Doxygen/index.html

How can we share our Doxygen documentation with our users through the codeplex site?

I know the alternative is to host the Doxygen files on a separate hosting provider. But I would like to have all data on one place.